# How can I crawl Dynamic website with Selenium? There's error 'NoSuchElementException'

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I've newly started to study Python and encountered `NoSuchElementException` while I'm doing crawling with SELENIUM.

I think target site is 'Dynamic webpage' hence I searched various way and tried but..... failed.
Would you help me? Thank in advance

> Target site : http://www.kofiabond.or.kr/index_en.html

What I need : Click area on below picture and move to that page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxnr1.png)

Below is the code which I made:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/SMH/chromedriver.exe')

url='http://www.kofiabond.or.kr/index_en.html'

driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()

xpath = "//*[@id='genLv1_0_imgLv1']"

open_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

driver.execute_script(open_btn)
```

Comment: It works!!! I sincerely appreciated your help. I learn new thing.^^

Answer (score 1):

To click on `Final Quotation Yields` link which is present inside an `iframe` you need to switch `iframe` first then `hover on the main menu` to element become `visible` on the page and then **click** on the `element`.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and hover on the element

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

---

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/SMH/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.kofiabond.or.kr/index_en.html')
#Switch to iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'fraAMAKMain')))
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[./img[@alt='bond Interest Rates']]")))
#Hover main menu
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
#Click on the element once become clickable
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[./div[text()='Final Quotation Yields']]"))).click()
```

---

**Browser snapshot**

[image]